# Does there exist a field ${K[X]}/{(p)}$ where $p$ is reducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Suppose a ring $K$. Does there exist a field ${K[X]}/{(p)}$ where $p \in K[X]$ and p is reducible?

I know that as soon as $(p)$ is a maximum ideal from $K[X]$ that ${K[X]}/{(p)}$ is a field. Furthermore, if $K$ is a Principal ideal domain(PID) then $p$ is irreducible iff $(p)$ is a maximal ideal. So $K$ can't be a PID and therefore also not a field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $p$ is reducible, then you can factor it non-trivially $p = p_1 p_2$ and the product of $p_1 + (p)$ and $p_2 + (p)$ in $K[X]/(p)$ will be zero. Thus $K[X]/(p)$ is not an integral domain, let alone a field.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and straight forward answer!